# How do I permanently close the master document toolbar in Word 2011?

Tags: microsoft-word-2011, microsoft-office-2011

When working with documents in outline view in Word 2011 it occasionally opens a "Master Document" toolbar in-between the Mac menu and the document. When it does it resizes the document window a bit to fit the toolbar:

[image]

**How do I permanently get rid of this toolbar?**

I can click on the small close icon and it will go away for this session. I then have to resize the window again.

However it pops up next time I run Word and open an outline document. I have also tried clicking on the side arrow to select "customize toolbar and menus" and disabling it there; it still shows up next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick to getting the Master Document toolbar to stay closed is to change the view type after you close the toolbar and before you save. So close the tool bar, change the view, then save.

I never would have guessed this myself, but I picked up the answer from Microsoft Answers [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macword/how-do-i-permanently-close-the-master-document/bd01f526-43e6-4c99-b3dc-03c1df675bf6). Here is his answer:

> That toolbar is actually triggered by **View> Master Document**. If you
>   dismiss the toolbar then switch to a different view & back to Outline
>   View the toolbar will not return.
>        I believe this is specific to individual documents though. Once Master Document has been invoked in any given file it will persist
>   until you do as above.